# What does DefaultVerbosity and CompileTimeVerbosity means in macro DEFINE_LOG_CATEGORY_STATIC from Unreal Engine?

Tags: unreal-engine5

Lately I'm learning Unreal Engine C++ programing, when topic comes to UE_LOG, and defining our own logging category by using DEFINE_LOG_CATEGORY_STATIC, I'm confused about DefaultVerbosity and CompileTimeVerbosity.

This is the Marco

```
DEFINE_LOG_CATEGORY_STATIC(CategoryName, DefaultVerbosity, CompileTimeVerbosity)

UE_LOG(CategoryName, Verbosity,...)
```

In my understanding, when the verbosity given in UE_LOG is bigger than the CompileTimeVerbosity, the UE_LOG sentence won't be added to the code.

When the verbosity is no bigger than CompileTimeVerbosity, it will be compiled.

But if the verbosity is bigger than DefaultVerbosity, it will not be printed.

When I define my own logging category like this

```
DEFINE_LOG_CATEGORY_STATIC(LogBaseGeometory, Error, Error)
```

and use UE_LOG like this

```
UE_LOG(LogBaseGeometory, Error, TEXT("info"));
```

the output is empty.

I don't know why this happens, either I misunderstood CompileTimeVerbosity or some special setting I missed.

It would be appreciated if you could help me figure this out.